# Need to add a html file (page) in wordpress website

Tags: html, wordpress

I've a wordpress website, I'm also have a html page. Now I need to add the separate html page to wordpress.

This is an well designed order form. I want to add the order form in to my wordpress site. I need a "OrderNOw" menu and when visitor click on this menu then order form page will show and customer will fill the form and able to submit an order to me.

Please give me a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I usually create a [template page](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) in the current theme from the given HTML (remember to rename the extension to `.php`).

Then create a new page from the Wordpress administration and set the *Template* field accordingly (just set the title and leave the content blank).

Finally you just need to add this page to your menu.